# FileOutputStream in JSP

Tags: java, jsp, fileoutputstream

I am building a JSP based website and I am trying to add a FileOutputStream in my java code that will be called as the page is generated and present the user with a file to download.  However; the FileOutputStream breaks the page.  Is it possible to add a FileOutputStream to JSP without a serverlet as a listener?

Comment: How do you want to handle the download process if you don't have a servlet available?

Comment: Is using a serverlet the only way to download a file?  If so, what is an alternative way I can create an excel file for the user in jsp?

Comment: breaks the page ? what you mean of it ?

Comment: The page wont render because of the java error.

Comment: JSP is the mere presentation for the view. It makes no sense to do such a process there IMO. Also, you should attach some code you've tried, otherwise the question sounds too broad.